# Windows laptop blue screens after waking from sleep

Tags: windows, ubuntu, laptop, bsod, sleep

**Hardware/Operating System:**
 Lenovo Yoga 720 running Windows 10 alongside Ubuntu

**The Issue:**
After waking my computer from sleep I am greeted by a ***blue screen*** with the error *`PAGE_FAULT_IN_NONPAGED_AREA`*. Sometimes it happens immediately after wake, but other times it seems to be caused by shutting down the computer. *See dump file below*

**The Story:**
About six months ago I decided to setup my laptop as a dual-boot of Windows 10 *(the pre-installed OS)* and the latest version of Ubuntu. This turned out to be harder than expected due to the ***SATA controller*** being set to ***RAID*** by factory. After following advice from others I was able to change the ***SATA controller*** to ***AHCI***, install Ubuntu, and boot back into Windows. Both operating systems work fine except for one issue. Windows commonly greets me with a blue screen after waking from a decently long sleep.

I am at a point where I don't want to cause any more issues. I have thought that maybe changing the ***SATA controller*** back to ***RAID*** could fix the issue, but I do not know if doing so will fix the issue or make my computer more unstable.

**The Dump File:** 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1NZ3PpOfQjQeDjOQZm-OjeP3fkDySCGRh/view?usp=sharing

*This is what I got after running it through WinDbg:*
https://pastebin.com/Q5EdGYUk

Comment: Can you please post the minidump file to a file sharing service, and update yyour Q to include the link?

Comment: @JamieHanrahan is the file I posted a "minidump"?

Comment: Sorry, no. Look in c:\windows\minidump